# Grammatical term for inflectable conjunctions as used in the Arabic language(s)

Tags: terminology, arabic, inflection, conjunctions

Conjunctions in the Arabic language can be inflected be adding an affix that indicates the pronoun.

E.g. the conjunction 'because' is لِأَن (li'ann), and 'because you' yields لِأَنك (li'annak).
This is an example sentence: 'You are sick, **because you** didn't were a scarf'.

Is there a grammatical term that labels this class of conjunctions.

Comment: So it's introducing a topicalised subject. Does the personal suffix appear on the verb as well?

Comment: A personal suffix or prefix (depending on the tense) appears on the verb as well. @ColinFine

Comment: For example the conjugation of verbs in the present tense works with applying pronoun specific prefixes. The past tense is conjugated with use of suffixes.

Comment: I think it is called: connected pronouns الضمائر المتصلة

Comment: @user2824371 What is **it**? Are you referring to a grammatical trait of pronouns, so that in the end my question is not about conjunctions, but about the connectivity of pronouns in semitic languages? In that case should the question be rephrased, or is it a valid question as it is?

Comment: @mike Yes it is not about the conjunction itself. It is not about the word (because). It's about the pronoun itself. I wrote an answer. Is it now clear for you?

Answer (score 1):

In Arabic grammar this is called "'inna and its sisters". These encompass a set of particles that are followed by a noun in the accusative case, or by the accusative forms of suffixed pronouns.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. I didn't learn of "inna and its sisters" (yet). So I can't fully  utilize this answer in its current form right now.

Answer (score 1):

The character **ل**  can be used as a preposition. The preposition means "for".

The word **أن** means "that".

When you combine the preposition **ل**  and the word **أن** together, It becomes the word **لأن**. The preposition and the word are connected together because the preposition **ل** is always connected to the next word.

The meaning of the word **لأن**  is "for that" but the actual meaning is "**because**".

Now, There are two ways to say "because you".

You means **انت**

So, (Because you) = **لأن انت**  (it is understandable but it is not commonly used)

The other way is to use connectivity of pronouns in semitic languages. I mean pronouns are able to be connected (embedded or compressed) to a word. In this case, The pronoun will take the form of an object pronoun.

To learn more about object pronouns you can watch this video. I've made it myself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiypiNzmc80